# create github organisation using API

Tags: github-api

I am trying to create organisation using github enterprise API, i am following this -

> https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/rest/reference/enterprise-admin#create-an-organization

Below is the API tried :

```
curl -u acme-admin:token  -X POST   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"   https://acme.example.com/api/v3/admin/organizations   -d '{"login":"acme-admin","admin":"acme-admin","profile_name":"exampleorg"}'
```

Response is as shown below, do any one have any clue about this ? the user "acme-admin" exists in the github enterprise and this user is administrator only.

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Organization",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "login",
      "message": "login is not available"
    },
    {
      "resource": "Organization",
      "code": "missing_field",
      "field": "admins"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/2.22/user/rest/reference/enterprise-admin#create-an-organization"
}
```

Comment: Hi, Are you able to create a user without organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [similar script](https://gist.github.com/blaggacao/e7e324d53aee7304fb3f5a48199874e8) mentions:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token $gitub_api_token" ...
```

You can see that header defined in "[REST API / Other authentication methods](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#authenticating-for-saml-sso)".
Check if this works better than  `-u acme-admin:token`.

Comment: Yes - just tried using curl -i -H "Authorization: token $gitub_api_token" ...i still encounter this same issue especially same error as mentioned above. We are trying to find the way to automate the workflow without manual intervention.

Comment: @harekrshn Strange. Is it possible the token has not the correct right for creating organization?

Comment: Can you confirm which token i should use ? I manually created the token using developer settings -> personal access tokens -> generated token with all admin privileges. Is this right one ?